# How to calculate regression between three stacks in R?

Tags: r, raster, terra

To compute local regression, that is, a regression model for each grid cell (pixel), you can do use

```
library(terra)
s <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   
## the 1 is to get a slope. 
## 1:nlyrs(s) is the independent variable    
X <- cbind(1, 1:nlyr(s))
## pre-computing constant part of least squares
invXtX <- solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X)
## [2] is to just get the slope
quickfun <- function(y) (invXtX %*% y)[2]
slope <- app(s, quickfun) 
plot(slope)
```

How to do this using three stacks:

```
s <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra")) 
s1 <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra")) 
s2 <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))
```

use s1 and s2 (per pixel) to predict s with taking each pixel as time series. So at the end, each pixel (time series of the three layers) will have its own slope and intercept.

Comment: I do not understand what you are looking for. Can you provide an example `(g)lm` formula for a single grid cell?

Comment: Sorry about that I want to apply glm (not lm as stated). for each pixl grid i want to apply this  `x<-glm(s~s1+s2)`.

Comment: Imagine the first pixel from s is p (which will have 3 values),the first pixel from s1 is p1 (which will have 3 values),the first pixel from s2 is p2 (which will have 3 values). how can the 3 values of p1+the 3 of p2   explain the three values of p. (it is like three columns in a data frame in short).

Answer (score 1):

So for one cell, it would go like this:

```
d <- data.frame(y=1:3, x1=c(0.1, 0.3, 0.4), x2=c(9, 8, 6))
lm(y ~ x1+ x2, data=d) |> coefficients()
#(Intercept)          x1          x2 
#  3.6666667   3.3333333  -0.3333333
```

Example data with these values for each cell

```
library(terra)    
y <- rast(ncol=10, nrow=10, nlyr=3, vals=rep(1:3, each=100))
x1 <- setValues(y, rep(c(0.1, 0.3, 0.4), each=100))
x2 <- setValues(y, rep(c(9, 8, 6), each=100))    
rr <- c(y, x1, x2)
```

For testing always add some NA's

```
rr[1:5] <- NA
```

A function that, for each cell, does the regression

```
f <- function(x) {
    if (any(is.na(x))) return(c(NA, NA, NA))
    d <- data.frame(matrix(x, ncol=3))
    names(d) <- c("y", "x1", "x2")
    coefficients( lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=d) )
}
```

Test it

```
f(c(1:3,  0.1,0.3,0.4,  9,8,6))
#(Intercept)          x1          x2 
#  3.6666667   3.3333333  -0.3333333
```

And use it with `app`

```
a <- app(rr, f)
a
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#source      : memory 
#names       : (Intercept),         x1,         x2 
#min values  :   3.6666667,  3.3333333, -0.3333333 
#max values  :   3.6666667,  3.3333333, -0.3333333
```

The linear algebra notation goes like this

```
ff <- function(v) {
    X <- cbind(1, matrix(v[-c(1:3)], ncol=2))
    solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% v[1:3])
}

b <- app(rr, ff)
```

That should be faster, but it is possible that `solve` fails with your data. And you would need to replace the hard-coded `1:3` with the actual number of layers (length of time-series) in your data

Comment: Thank you so much. I have 30 layers and  with a spatial resolution of 5km. Is there a way to use foreach or any methods to run it faster with less memory, please?

Comment: `app` has an argument `cores` for parallelization, and see `?terraOptions` for memory management

Comment: Thanks alot, last thing please if i have 20 layers, what I shall change in the f function?

Comment: You do not need to change it.